Importing custom enum not working in generated Prisma Client
I am building a Nuxt application and hosting it on digitalOcean.
I am using Prisma as ORM.
We have a Users table, and this User can have a Role which is of enum type Roles. But for some reason I am not able to import the Roles type which is in the generated Nuxt
import { Roles, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

SyntaxError: Named export 'Roles' not found. The requested module '@prisma/client' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
import pkg from '@prisma/client';
const { Roles, PrismaClient } = pkg;

I am not able to import it this way because the file is generated automatically.
It works fine locally, I have tried the following things:

Force rebuild and deploy in digitalOcean app
Set prisma client to different output location
Move prisma from devDepenencies to dependencies
Compared node versions
Compared Prisma versions
made sure to run npx prisma generate and npx prisma migrate deploy straight after running npm run build
Resetting the database

NOTE: Before adding the Roles enum to the code, I always got the following error while running the production environment, even though I had run npx prisma generate adter npm run build:
@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
Any help would be appreciated

I think you use enum in table and after that it would be generated for import in prisma without using enum in table in prisma it can't be generated for use

To fix my issue, I created by own Roles enum instead of importing the one from Prisma.
The chance that this was related to the @prisma/client did not initialize yet issue is high. I fixed this issue by running npx prisma generate before running npm run build.

After finding out that the Enum import issue was definetely related to the prisma client not being generated, I could also go ahead and remove my superflous typescript enum.
